# how to get data using $in from object array?

Tags: mongodb

i have database like

```
 "profile" : {
    "firstName" : "dh",
    "lastName" : "french",
    "roles" : [ 
        "applicant"
    ]
},
```

i want to find whose roles is `applicant`
so i try this query

```
 var data = Meteor.users.find({
        "profile.roles": { $in: ["applicant"] }
    }).fetch();
```

but i always get 0 length data
so,which query is righ

Comment: your query structure is correct, but in your sample you're looking for `admin`, not `applicant`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to use `$in` operator. Take is easy:

```
 Meteor.users.find({
    "profile.roles": "applicant"
 }).fetch();
```